# Create elements for datalist in d3

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I am trying to add option elements to a datalist by populating entries from a csv file in D3. From what I understand, I have selected my datalist, loaded the csv with the entries from the column NAME, binded my data, and should be appending to the datalist with options with the value for the data. I am not quite sure why elements aren't being made and I assume it has to do with how my data is being handled.

```
d3.select("datalist")
.data(d3.csv("Input/domain_data.csv").row(function(d){return d.NAME}))
.enter()
.append("option")
.attr("value", function(d){return d})
```

Comment: I would venture a guess that d3.csv is asynchronous and thus doesn't return anything immediately.

Comment: Load your CSV in a function and then, inside it, append your options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `d3.csv` is asynchronous, meaning you need to setup a callback and *wait* for the response to arrive. Second, you need to call `data` on a selection of `<option>`s, i.e.: `selectAll('option')` to be able to append to them.

```
// Start off by doing an HTTP request to a server:
d3.csv('path/to/file.csv')
  .row(function (d) { return d.NAME })
  .get(function (error, rows) {
    // The response from the server has arrived (maybe check for errors too?).
    // Let's create an empty selection of options inside a datalist:
    d3.select('datalist').selectAll('option')
      .data(rows) // performing a data join
      .enter() // extracting the entering selection
      .append('option') // adding an option to the selection of options
      .attr('value', function (d) { return d; }); // add attribute
  });
```